# Using live() on setTimeout events

Tags: jquery, settimeout, live

So I have these two segments of code.

```
$(".hideMessage").live("click", function(event) {
   $('.messageSuccess').hide("slow");
   return false;
});
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $(".messageSuccess").hide("slow") 
}, 10000);
```

Basically the first segment hides `.messageSuccess` when `.hideMessage` is clicked, and uses `live()` so if I have any `.messageSuccess` generated afterwards thru AJAX, I can still reach them.

The second segment hides `.messageSuccess` if the user doesn't click the `.hideMessage` link in the 10 sec span. Question is, how can I use `live()` in this second segment as well so I can control the AJAX generated `.messageSuccess`?

Comment: You should use the `on()` event. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Not exactly sure what you after but if you are executing an ajax request and wish to hide the elements after the request is done you could use the success or complete callback of the ajax request? Hard to tell exactly without seeing the code for the ajax request.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl see my comment below
Yeah, that's what I'm doing now ... but I didn't want to embed the setTimeout code in the response every time, I just wanted to do it once - like I did with the first line using live()

Comment: @user1735943: You could hook up the code to the global ajax success I think. Have a look at the [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) and specifcially the [.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) event handler. Maybe you can work something out with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know whenever a new `.messageSuccess` element is added in order to set the timeout at the moment of creation.  The best option is to modify your script to set the timeout whenever the new element is added.  However, if you cannot do this (e.g. third-party script you don't control), then you need to setup a polling interval to check for new elements' existence.

For example:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('div.messageSuccess').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('hideScheduled'))
            return;
        $this.data('hideScheduled', true);
        setTimeout(function(toHide){ toHide.hide('slow'); }, 10000, $this);
    });
}, 2000);
```

This script will automatically hide any new `div.messageSuccess` elements 10-12 seconds after they come into existence.

Comment: @N Rohler
My problem is that if the .messageSuccess is generated after the page is loaded (thru an AJAX call) I cannot control it if I don't bind it with live(). Which I did, for the first line, but I don't know how to do it for the second line.

Comment: I'm not sure if you read my answer ;)  How does `.messageSuccess` come into existence?

Comment: It is generated as a response to an $.get(ajax) call. I make a $.get(ajax) call to a php file => run a query => generate the .messageSuccess back in the page (no reloading).

Comment: Then you need to set the timeout in the `$.get()` response handler.  This will make sure that it's hidden 10000msec after being created.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now ... but I didn't want to embed the setTimeout code in the response every time, I just wanted to do it once - like I did with the first line using live().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, because `$(".messageSuccess")` selects all `.messageSuccess` elements currently in the DOM regardless of whether they were added by AJAX or not.

On an unrelated note, if you're using jQuery 1.7+ update `.live` to `.on`.